# Authorization header in a POST request to Azure Tables

Tags: azure, header, authorization, azure-table-storage

I've done and tried everything in order to Insert an Entity to an Azure Table, but so far, I still get the same error "StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.'"

Now, i've tried to use ShareKey and SharedKeyLite (Azure Storage Explorer uses SharedKeyLite)

```
public static async Task<string> InsertEntityAsync(string tableName, Position position)
    {
        string uri = @"https://" + Utilities.Account + ".table.core.windows.net/" + tableName;
        return await Utilities.UploadEntityAsync(tableName,uri,position);
    }
public static async Task<string> UploadEntityAsync(string urlPath, string uri, Position position)
    {
        string body = buildBodyForInsertOperation(position);

        HttpClient request = new HttpClient();
        string formatedTime = Authentication.FormatedTime();
        request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", formatedTime);

        //Adding the Authorization header to the request
        string authorization = Authentication.GetSignedString("POST",formatedTime, urlPath, Utilities.Account, Utilities.Key);
        request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorization);

        request.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", body.Length.ToString());


        HttpResponseMessage messageResult = await request.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(body, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/atom+xml"));
        return messageResult.ToString();
    }

 public static string GetSignedString(string httpMethod, string time, string urlPath, string account, string key)
    {
           String contentMD5 = String.Empty;
String contentType = "application/atom+xml";
String canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", account, urlPath);
String stringToSign = String.Format(
      "{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}",
      httpMethod,
      contentMD5,
      contentType,
      time,
      canonicalizedResource);

        string signedKey = SignThis(stringToSign, key, account);
        return signedKey;
    }
    private static String SignThis(String canonicalizedString,string Key, string Account)
    {
        String signature = string.Empty;
        byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
        using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
        {
            Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
        }

        String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
              "{0} {1}:{2}",
              "SharedKeyLite",
              Account,
              signature);

        return authorizationHeader;
    }
```

The time parameter is formatted according to what Azure requires, other than that i don't know what else to or try. I've tried to make the request without the httpMethod, without contentMD5, wthout content-type and all sort of combinations, but still.

I'm and pretty sure the SignThis(...) method works cause i'm using it to also sign GET requests to query Entities, so any help or words would help me a lot. Thanks

/*Edited*/
I'm attaching the UploadEntityAsync method, in my case i have a Table called Position in Azure, so i'm building the XML, anyway, that's not what's wrong cause i've compared my buided XML with the one of Azure Storage Explorer using Fiddler, and the're o'k. Only problem is the Signature

Comment: Your code above does not include `Content-Type` request header. Based on the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179433.aspx (and also mentioned in my response below) that it is required.

Comment: Actually it is included, but HTTP Client can't include Content-Type directly, so it's included on the body, when I remove this, again, the problem is the Signature, not the other headers, which actually show errors when are not present

Comment: Sorry! My bad. Didn't see it. Let me try it out on my end and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found some issues with the code:

- You have chosen to use **`SharedKeyLite`** however the format you're using to create the `stringToSign` in your code is for **`SharedKey`**. If you want to use `SharedKeyLite`, please try to create `stringToSign` using something like below:

  ```
      stringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n{1}", time, canonicalizedResource);
  ```

For more details, please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx

- I found an issue with the way you're creating `StringContent`. For some reason, if I use your code, I always get 403 error. Try this instead:

  ```
      var stringContent = new StringContent(body);
      stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/atom+xml");
      HttpResponseMessage messageResult = await request.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
  ```

Try this code instead. It makes use of SharedKey:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SOPostToAzureTable
{
    static class Utilities
    {
        internal static string Account = "account name";

        internal static string Key = "account key";
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => InsertEntityAsync("SOTest"));
            Task[] tasks = new Task[1];
            tasks[0] = task;
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task<string> InsertEntityAsync(string tableName)
        {
            string uri = @"https://" + Utilities.Account + ".table.core.windows.net/" + tableName;
            return await UploadEntityAsync(tableName, uri);
        }
        public static async Task<string> UploadEntityAsync(string urlPath, string uri)
        {
            string body = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
                                <entry 
                                        xmlns:d=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"" 
                                        xmlns:m=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"" 
                                        xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"">
                                    <title />
                                    <updated>2013-08-30T21:03:45.4991966Z</updated>
                                    <author>
                                        <name />
                                    </author>
                                    <id />
                                    <content type=""application/xml"">
                                      <m:properties>
                                      <d:PartitionKey>SOTest</d:PartitionKey>
                                      <d:RowKey>{0}</d:RowKey>
                                      <d:A m:type=""Edm.String"">A</d:A><d:B m:type=""Edm.String"">B</d:B>
                                  </m:properties>
                                    </content>
                                </entry>";
            body = string.Format(body, Guid.NewGuid());

            HttpClient request = new HttpClient();
            string formatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
            request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", formatedTime);

            //Adding the Authorization header to the request
            string authorization = GetSignedString("POST", formatedTime, urlPath, Utilities.Account, Utilities.Key);
            request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorization);

            request.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", body.Length.ToString());
            var stringContent = new StringContent(body);
            stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/atom+xml");
            HttpResponseMessage messageResult = await request.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
            return messageResult.ToString();
        }

        public static string GetSignedString(string httpMethod, string time, string urlPath, string account, string key)
        {
            String contentMD5 = String.Empty;
            String contentType = "application/atom+xml";
            String canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", account, urlPath);
            //stringToSign format for SharedKey
            String stringToSign = String.Format(
                  "{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}",
                  httpMethod,
                  contentMD5,
                  contentType,
                  time,
                  canonicalizedResource);
            //stringToSign format for SharedKeyLite
            //stringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n{1}", time, canonicalizedResource);
            string signedKey = SignThis(stringToSign, key, account);
            return signedKey;
        }

        private static String SignThis(String canonicalizedString, string Key, string Account)
        {
            String signature = string.Empty;
            byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
            using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
            {
                Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }

            String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                  "{0} {1}:{2}",
                  "SharedKey",
                  Account,
                  signature);

            return authorizationHeader;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm actually using application/atom+xml on both my request and my signature, and still get the error 403

Comment: Can you share the complete code by updating your original post? Since you mentioned that the code above is working fine for your GET requests, I am guessing something's wrong with the way you're creating request.

Comment: I'll work on it and let you know what happened, thanks for helping!

Comment: Still nothing, i've tried with SharedKey, SharedKeyLite.
I've also tried the StringContent you wrote, seems it works, but I still get error 403, telling me the AuthorizationHeader is the one that's incorrect. And nothing :(

Comment: Have you tried running my code? Create a new console app using the code above and give it a try (just change the account name and key). Only other thing I could think of now is the account key. Please double check if the account key is correct.

Comment: Tried your code on a console project and still get the same result.

Comment: This is totally weird! You mentioned that your GET requests are working and you're getting errors only in the POST requests. Am I correct? Can you please check your computer's date/time. What I did was set the computer's clock back by 1 hour and the request start failing with 403 error.

Comment: Yup it's totally weird, it workds with my GET requests, the clock on my computer is fine, but even so, i tried to modify that to see if something happened, I did the same thing on my Phone and nothing, I'm this close to look somewhere else for getting my table entities, maybe using WCF Services

Comment: One last thing you may want to try - run the console application I wrote (or run your code) and trace the request/response through Fiddler. Usually Fiddler will have more details about the 403 error. It would be helpful if you post the Fiddler's request body and response details along with your question above. BTW, what's the locale and timezone on your computer?

Comment: Actually I'm using Fiddler since the begining, i'm on GMT-04, but already checked if that was somehow causing the problem

Comment: Done! It was there all the way, just had to fix the XML build, thx for your help @Gaurav